# Is it possible to send a interface instance along with the image picker intent?

Tags: android, interface

I want to use a interface instance in onActivityResult() of image picker intent. I know that interface instance can be passed by serializable using normal intents.But this might not be possible in the case of image picker intents as shown below.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
myIntent.putExtra("interface", mListener); //interface instance
myIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Select..."), 111);
```

I wanted to use the interface instance either by saving it on SharedPreferences or in any other way.If it is possible,how to save a interface instance and retrieve it for further usage?

Comment: you can save the interface to the field of your class, and use that field in onActivityResult

Comment: @VladMatvienko The problem here is i`m using the interface and intent call in another custom view class.I need to pass the interface instance to the main activity class

Answer (score -1):

I create getter and setter class for the interface instance and get it solved using the singleton pattern